# How can I restrict Find Results 1 to have just the latest set of results?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017 (perhaps in a recent update to it) the behavior of Find in Files seems to have changed.

Before, the results would show in Find Results 1.  A new Find in Files would replace the previous one.

Now, Find Results 1 contains multiple sets of results.  Each new set is added to the window instead of replacing the previous one.

Unfortunately, this [breaks my workflow](https://xkcd.com/1172/) because I assign Control-N and Control-Shift-N to move through the results, and these shortcuts move through *all* the results, not just the most recent set.

How can I get the previous Find in Files behavior back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I ran across the answer as I was typing this up.

In the Find in Files (aka Find and Replace) dialog, expand the `Result Options` section.

There's a new checkbox there: `Append results`.

Uncheck it!